# UiScrollview scrollviewDidScroll detect user touch

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I am using a `UIScrollView` in my app, and use the `scrollviewDidScroll` method to move some other views that are not inside the scrollview. This behavior should only occur when the user is actually moving the scrollview with a finger and not when the touch event ends.

Currently I am using the `dragging` property of the scrollview to get this behavior, but it has a problem: when the user swipes over the scrollview and touches it again before it stopped decelerating, the `dragging` property is not true although the user is dragging the scrollview with a finger.

Comment: Look into `UIGestureRecognizerState` of your tableView, like `yourTableView.panGestureRecognizer.state`. It will reveal what exactly the state of the user's touch is. Do it in `scrollViewDidScroll`.

Comment: Done. With sample code

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The `UIScrollView` has a `panGestureRecogniser` property, which tracks the pan gestures in the scroll view. You can track the `state` of the pan gesture in the `scrollViewDidScroll` to know exactly what state the panning is in.

**Swift 4.0**

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.isEqual(yourScrollView) {
        switch scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.state {
            case .began:
                // User began dragging
                print("began")
            case .changed:
                // User is currently dragging the scroll view
                print("changed")
            case .possible:
                // The scroll view scrolling but the user is no longer touching the scrollview (table is decelerating)
                print("possible")
            default:
                break
        }
    }
}
```

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    if ([scrollView isEqual:yourScrollView]) {

        switch (scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.state) {

            case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:

                // User began dragging
                break;

            case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:

                // User is currently dragging the scroll view
                break;

            case UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible:

                // The scroll view scrolling but the user is no longer touching the scrollview (table is decelerating)
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

IMO better answer is use of `UIScrollViewDelegate`, there are following notifications:

```
// called on start of dragging (may require some time and or distance to move)
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
// called on finger up if the user dragged. velocity is in points/millisecond. targetContentOffset may be changed to adjust where the scroll view comes to rest
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
// called on finger up if the user dragged. decelerate is true if it will continue moving afterwards
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate;
```

Comment: You also will need to listen `scrollViewDidScrollToTop`.

Comment: @kelin how this related to user touch?

Comment: This event is getting called when user double-touches the Status Bar. This causing the table view to scroll to top. Read more in `UIScrollViewDelegate` documentation.

Comment: and how this is related to question?

Answer (score 1):

```
var lastVelocityYSign = 0

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let currentVelocityY =  scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.velocity(in: scrollView.superview).y
    let currentVelocityYSign = Int(currentVelocityY).signum()
    if currentVelocityYSign != lastVelocityYSign &&
        currentVelocityYSign != 0 {
        lastVelocityYSign = currentVelocityYSign
    }
    if lastVelocityYSign < 0 {
        print("SCROLLING DOWN")
    } else if lastVelocityYSign > 0 {
        print("SCOLLING UP")
    }
}
```

**Answer from Mos6y**
    https://medium.com/@Mos6yCanSwift/swift-ios-determine-scroll-direction-d48a2327a004